# throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.') causing crash

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
router.get('/newsfeed', (req, res, next) => {
var sql = 'select title, image, article from database';
var request = new Request(sql, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
console.log("working");
request.on('row', function(columns) {
    var t_title = columns[0].value;
    var i_image = columns[1].value;
    var a_article = columns[2].value;
    console.log("after column");
    res.render('newsfeed', { title: t_title, image: i_image, article: a_article });
    console.log("after render");
});
console.log("not here");
conn.execSql(request);
console.log("after request")
```

});

i cant seem to find out how to stop this as it gets up to the consol.log("after render") as seen here:

```
working
not here
after request
after column
after render
after column
after render
```

and then it crashes with the throw error any help would be great

Comment: You are doing multiple `res.render` calls per request.

Comment: I think you can't render multiple times

Comment: how can i make it do just one?

Comment: @noob coder await requests end, then send one response

Comment: @Jonasw how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The `row` event fires once per row.

You can only send a response once, so you get that error when you try to send a second response for the second row.

Comment: so is there a command to make it just do it once as also want it to try and make it dynamically load the content from the database

Comment: @noobcoder: If you only want one row, change your SQL to only return one row.

Comment: would this be selecting the ID in the database maybe?

Comment: if you could give an example code to return one row that would be great as still learning the language

Comment: That completely depends on which row you actually want.

Comment: just the first for now to see if i can get it working as it is sorted by content_id which increments with any new item added

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+get+first+row  Also, tables aren't ordered; if you want an order, you need `ORDER BY`.